# City map making (cartography) with GIMP.

Tags: gimp, brush, cartography, maps

Does anyone know of good city specific (although I would be interested in others as well) plug-ins for fantasy role playing game map making using [GIMP](http://www.gimp.org)?

I am more looking at macro-scale (so whole city and a little of country side) rather than a tactical map.

Edit: *I should have asked for brushes: [Deviant art](http://browse.deviantart.com/?qh=&section=&global=1&q=gimp%20brushes) has a plethora of brushes that can be used for this.*

Comment: GIMP probably isn't the tool for this; you'd normally use a vector-based app for maps, such as Adobe Illustrator or Inkscape.

Comment: Have you looked at any of the tools that already exist specifically designed to make gaming maps? Why stick with GIMP?

Comment: I'm pretty sure there is no plugin for 'make a map' for any software.

Comment: @Philip Regan: Most other tools are not free (as in GPL).  Plus, I know gimp fairly well.  Inkscape maybe a better tool for the job though.

Comment: @DA01: For sure.  But there maybe a plugin to draw a set of randomly connected lines (streets) with rectangles (houses) along the lines' path.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No plugins, but I did find a tutorial for creating a regional RPG map in the GIMP [here](http://www.cartographersguild.com/showthread.php?1142-Award-Winner-Using-GIMP-to-Create-an-Artistic-Regional-RPG-Map) that seems extremely complete.

The same forum has a few other tutorials for city mapmaking that are specific to Photoshop ([here](http://www.cartographersguild.com/showthread.php?1150-Award-Winner-A-medieval-town-map-tutorial-in-Photoshop), for example). Depending on your familiarity with PS and GIMP you might be able to translate some of the specifics over to GIMP on your own.